# Why do we take the degree of numerator 1 degree less than the denominator?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In expanding rational polynomials, I saw that if the degree of the denominator is 2, then the numerator is $Bx+C$. if the degree is 3, then it is $Bx^{2}+Cx+D$.

I felt that it might be because we want to keep track of all possible numerator there can be. But I want a solid example/proof which will practically show me the actual reason

Also, correct me if I am wrong, the degree doesn't become larger than the denominator as we can always divide it once and make the degree less than the denominator without  changing anything. Is this right?

Comment: When you do division, the remainder has degree strictly less than the divisor. If you are dividing by a polynomial of degree $2$, the remainder is either $0$, of degree $0$, or of degree $1$; you must take into account all possibilities. If you divide by a polynomial of degree $1$, then the remainder will be of degree $0$.

Comment: It's similar to wanting to write fractions in reduced form, e.g. we'd usually write $\frac{2}{3}$ instead of $\frac{8}{12}$. Also, it might not always be that the degree of the numerator is exactly one less than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. So we actually take that to remain safe, right? Like if we don't take care of all cases, one may slip out.

Comment: There may be no solutions if you don't do that. There is no way to write $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ in the form $\frac{A}{x^2+1}$, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* have a polynomial fraction with numerator and denominator of the same degree, like $\frac{Ax^2 + Bx + C}{Dx^2 + Ex + F}$, but then you could rewrite it in the form $\frac{A}{D} + \frac{Gx+H}{Dx^2+Ex+F}$ (where $G= B- \frac{AE}{D}$ and $H = C - \frac{AF}{D}$) and have a “simpler” fraction with degree one lower.

It's a convention of avoiding “improper” fractions, like writing $2 \frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{5}{2}$.